# How to insert datetimepicker default value to MYSQL with datetime column type?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datetime

I have 2 project, one is CRUD class and another is contain a WinForm that will access the CRUD class.
Here come my problem, everytime i trying to insert DateTimePicker with default value in MYSQL with datetime column type, i getting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` Zero zero zero and zero value, what i missed here?

Here is my part of CRUD class code, my CRUD class named DBConnect.cs

```
public DateTime property_dtDate { get; set; }

sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO master (NoInvoice, Name, Date, Type, Additionaltext) VALUES ('" + property_NoInvoice + "', '" + property_sName + "', '" + property_dtDate + "', '" + property_sType + "', '" + property_sAdditionalText + "')";
```

And here is my part of WinForm code, which is i named it Form1.cs (both is in separated project)

```
clsDbConnect.property_dtDate = DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

clsDbConnect.Insert();
```

I try look at the value with messagebox, a value that pass through my WinForm is good, nothing suspicious, it show the every date and time which is right know, but when i looked in my database, all i got is `0000-00-00 00:00:00.` I don't have any clue what cause that, help me to find out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem because of string format of the datetime. `MySQL` not understand your string format as a `datetime` value.
Try use parameters(assume somewhere in code you have a SqlCommand object):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO master (NoInvoice, Name, Date, Type, Additionaltext) VALUES (@NoInvoice, @sName, @dtDate, @sType, @sAdditionalText)";
using(SqlCommand command = New SqlCommand(query, yourconnection)
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoInvoice", property_NoInvoice);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName ", property_sName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtDate ", property_dtDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sType ", property_sType);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAdditionalText ", property_sAdditionalText);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Using parameters help with type safety(datetime and numerics format issues) and prevent a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Then when you don't need to parse a `datetimepicker`'s value to type `DateTime` because ti is already `DateTime` ([From MSDN: DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
clsDbConnect.property_dtDate = datetimepicker1.Value;
```

Comment: it worked! and i take your suggestion, thanks @fabio. i will keep it in my mind :)